# UDP server and 2 UDP clients in C

Tags: c, udp, udpclient

I read Beej's guide and created a UDP server and client. I first run the server and then run 2 clients. The server is supposed to `recevfrom` a client and `sendto` the other client. When client 1 sends something client 0 receives it. When client 0 sends something client 1 does not receive it. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code? I have read all questions on UDP, C, server, chat but was unable to find anything that helped me. I am compiling this code on OSX. Any help is appreciated. Following is the server code:

```
 #include <arpa/inet.h>  
 #include <netinet/in.h>  
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <sys/types.h>  
 #include <sys/socket.h>  
 #include <unistd.h>  
 #include <stdlib.h>  
 #include <string.h>  
 #define BUFLEN 512  
 #define PORT 7777  

 void err(char *str)  
 {  
     perror(str);  
     exit(1);  
 }  

 int main(void)  
 {  
     struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr[2],cli_temp;  
     int sockfd;  
     socklen_t slen[2],slen_temp;
     slen[1]=sizeof(cli_addr[1]); 
     slen[2]=sizeof(cli_addr[2]);
     slen_temp = sizeof(cli_temp);
     char buf[BUFLEN];  
     int clients = 0;
     int client_port[2];

     if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
     {
         printf("test\n");
         err("socket");  
     }else{  
         printf("Server : Socket() successful\n");  
     }   
     bzero(&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));  
     my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
     my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  
     my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr* ) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr))==-1)
     {
         err("bind");  
     }else{
         printf("Server : bind() successful\n");  
     }

     while(1)  
     {
         //receive
         printf("Receiving...\n");
         if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_temp, &slen_temp)==-1)  
             err("recvfrom()");
         if (clients==0) {
             //first connection
             //store the temp connection details to the array
             cli_addr[0] = cli_temp;
             //get client 0 port
             client_port[0] = ntohs(cli_addr[0].sin_port);
             clients++;
             printf("Client 0 connected. Port: %d\n",client_port[0]);
             sendto(sockfd, "You are the only client.", 24, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_temp, slen_temp);
         }else if (clients==1) {
             //new or existing
             if (client_port[0]==ntohs(cli_temp.sin_port)) {
                 //send back to client 0 that nobody else connected yet
                 sendto(sockfd, "You are the only client.", 24, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[0]);
                 printf("Only client\n");
             }else{
                 //new connection
                 cli_addr[1] = cli_temp;
                 client_port[1] = ntohs(cli_addr[1].sin_port);
                 clients++;
                 printf("GOt second client\n");
                 sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[0]);
             }
        }else{
            //there are 2 clients connected here. If we get an error from the sendto then we decrement clients
            if (client_port[0]==ntohs(cli_temp.sin_port)) {
                //client 0 talking send to client 1
                printf("Sedning message to client 1\n");
                if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
                {
                    clients--;
                    err("sendto()");
                }
            }else {
                //client 1 talking send to client 0
                printf("Sending message to client 0\n");
                if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
                {
                    clients--;
                    err("sendto()");
                }
            }

        }
        //printf("Received packet from %s:%d\nData: %s\n",  
        //        inet_ntoa(cli_addr[clients].sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr[clients].sin_port), buf);  
     }  

     close(sockfd);  
     return 0;  
}
```

And the client:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define BUFLEN 512  
#define PORT 7777  

void err(char *s)  
{  
    perror(s);  
    exit(1);  
}  
sig_atomic_t child_exit_status;

void clean_up_child_process (int signal_number) 
{
    /* Clean up the child process. */ 
    int status; 
    wait (&status); 
    /* Store its exit status in a global variable. */ 
    child_exit_status = status;
}
 int main(int argc, char** argv)  
 {  
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;  
     int sockfd, slen=sizeof(serv_addr);  
     char buf[BUFLEN];  
     struct sigaction sigchld_action; 
     memset (&sigchld_action, 0, sizeof (sigchld_action)); 
     sigchld_action.sa_handler = &clean_up_child_process; 
     sigaction (SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL);
     int pid,ppid;

     if(argc != 2)  
     {  
       printf("Usage : %s <Server-IP>\n",argv[0]);  
       exit(0);  
     }  

     if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)  
         err("socket");  

     bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));  
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  
     if (inet_aton(argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)==0)  
     {  
         fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");  
         exit(1);  
     }
     pid = fork();
     if (pid<0) {
         err("Fork Error");
     }else if (pid==0) {
         //child process will receive from server
         while (1) {
             bzero(buf,BUFLEN);
             printf("Attempting to READ to socket %d: ",sockfd);
             fflush(stdout);
             //recvfrom here
             if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &slen)==-1)  
                 err("recvfrom()");

             printf("The message from the server is: %s \n",buf);
             if (strcmp(buf,"bye\n") == 0) {
                 ppid = getppid();
                 kill(ppid, SIGUSR2);

                 break;
             }
         }
     }else {
         //parent will send to server
         while(1){
             printf("Please enter the message to send: ");
             bzero(buf,BUFLEN);
             fgets(buf,BUFLEN,stdin);
             printf("Attempting to write to socket %d: ",sockfd);
             fflush(stdout);
             //send to here
             if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, slen)==-1)
             {
                 err("sendto()");
             }
         }
     }
     close(sockfd);  
     return 0;  
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the following:

```
        // there are 2 clients connected here. If we get an error from the sendto
        // then we decrement clients
        if (client_port[0]==ntohs(cli_temp.sin_port)) {
            //client 0 talking send to client 1
            printf("Sedning message to client 1\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
        }else {
            //client 1 talking send to client 0
            printf("Sending message to client 0\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
        }
```

Notice that both sections (1 to 0, as well as 0 to 1) send to `&cli_addr[1]`.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You are unreal. Now it is working as it should. Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning of main, you've got this code:

```
 struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr[2],cli_temp;  
 int sockfd;  
 socklen_t slen[2],slen_temp;
 slen[1]=sizeof(cli_addr[1]); 
 slen[2]=sizeof(cli_addr[2]);
```

This should be changed to:

```
 struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr[2],cli_temp;  
 int sockfd;  
 socklen_t slen[2],slen_temp;
 slen[0]=sizeof(cli_addr[0]); 
 slen[1]=sizeof(cli_addr[1]);
```

I browsed the rest of your code and didn't see any other errors. I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but it's definitely wrong.

(you probably know this, but) it's wrong because the first element of an array is `array[0]`, not `array[1]`, so if you have an array with 2 elements, then `array[2]` won't exist.

### Update

Change

```
else {
            //client 1 talking send to client 0
            printf("Sending message to client 0\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[1], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
        }
```

to

```
else {
            //client 1 talking send to client 0
            printf("Sending message to client 0\n");
            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr[0], slen[1])==-1)
            {
                clients--;
                err("sendto()");
            }
        }
```

Comment: changed it but still the same.